# How Can I Have Apache & Nginx both behind Varnish?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, varnish, ubuntu-14.04

I have a setup where I have Varnish listening on Port 80 behind Apache on Port 8080 while I intend having Nginx on 8081. My vps' control panel supports only Apache but I want to test one of the sites I have hosted on my VPS on Nginx, and since Varnish is already on 80, I can't have Nginx on the same port.

I don't want to get rid of Apache completely cause I still need it to access my vps' control panel, [Sentora](http://sentora.org) to be precise where Apache sits on 8080. In the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208258/varnish-cache-1-server-2ips-2-websites), the OP wanted to have two different domains on different IP's on just Apache, so it doesn't really help.

Also, I read up somewhere about using the `server.port` directive in my vcl but I'm not sure how to go about it. Here's what a part of my `default.vcl` looks like:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

P.S: I haven't installed Nginx yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you want to set up an additional backend in Varnish, and route some requests to it.

First add a new backend for Nginx:

```
backend nginx {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8081";
}
```

Then you can route some requests to it. This is typically done in the `vcl_recv` subroutine. For example, if Sentora is accessed through the domain `sentora.example.org`:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host ~ "(?i)^sentora.example.org$") {
        # Route requests to sentora.example.org to the old Apache backend.
        set req.backend = default;
    } else {
        # Everything else to nginx.
        set req.backend = nginx;
    }
}
```

See [Advanced Backend configuration](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/advanced_backend_servers.html) for more examples. There are also a lot of examples in the [Varnish Configuration Language](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#examples) documentation.

Comment: hmm, awesome, what if Sentora is accessed from the vps's dedicated ip address on a specific port 8080?

Comment: @Feyisayo: I'm not sure I follow -- if Sentora is accessed on a dedicated IP and specific port, I assume it isn't accessed through Varnish? In that case, you would not need to route any requests in Varnish to Sentora, and can drop that route.

Comment: Yeah, its accessed through varnish on the same Apache 8080 port. Something like `http://serverip:8080`

Comment: But you said Varnish is running on port 80, while Apache is running on port 8080? If you access Sentora through `http://serverip:8080/`, you are accessing Apache directly, bypassing Varnish.

Comment: Wow, thanks for clarifying, so if I access Sentora directly without the port number, it goes through Varnish? Also what happens if I change this port number for Sentora, it still doesn't go through Varnish right?

Comment: Yes, if you access `http://serverip/`, Varnish receives the request, and is responsible for routing it to a backend (depending on the configuration you have created). Not sure what you mean with "change this port number for Sentora". Sentora in itself does not appear to have a port number. You can change the port number of Apache, at which point you will have to access Sentora through a different port. (And also update your Varnish configuration).

Comment: Thank you so much, I really didn't know Sentora doesn't have its own port. All this while I thought me accessing Sentora with the port number in the url was going through Varnish.

Comment: Hey Olav, I can't get Varnish to work without it complaining about `req.backend` being an unknown variable when I try to start it. I have Varnish 4 installed and looks like the syntax has changed for `req.backend`

Comment: EDIT: Never mind, I figured out, its now `req.backend_hint`.

Comment: Yes, you had tagged your question with Ubuntu 14.04, so I assumed that you were running Varnish 3 (based on http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/varnish).